# WCF proxy wrapper - buffering data offline, reconnect and send once back online

Tags: c#, wcf, error-handling, fault

I have written a wrapper around a WCF class that will buffer up send data, and send once reconnected. I have the following questions please:

1. Do I need to suscribe to all the channel faulted events, or is ChannelFactory.Faulted enough?
2. This has bene written after a many late nights and would appreciate a fresh set of eyes, can anyone see anything alarming with the below?
3. Any recommended reading for implementation of general reconnects and best practice (I have seen the Polly library but cant see how that would perform reconnects in a background thread) so I dont reinvent the wheel? Any generic frameworks to achieve what I have tried to write

Please see my code below:

```
public class ClientProxyWrapper
{
    private readonly Action<Dictionary<string, string>> _incomingCallCallback;
    private ScreenPopClient _proxy;
    private volatile bool _isConnecting;
    private volatile bool _isReady;
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private readonly InstanceContext _context;
    private TreadSafeStack<Dictionary<string,string> _offlineValues = new TreadSafeStack<Dictionary<string,string>();

    public ClientProxyWrapper(Action<Dictionary<string,string>> incomingCallCallback)
    {
        _isReady = false;
        _incomingCallCallback = incomingCallCallback;
        _context = new InstanceContext(this);
        StartConnectTask(0);
    }

    void CreateNewProxy()
    {
        _proxy = new ScreenPopClient(_context);
        _proxy.ChannelFactory.Faulted += OnChannelFault;
        _proxy.InnerChannel.Faulted += OnChannelFault;            
        _proxy.InnerDuplexChannel.Faulted += OnChannelFault;            
    }

    void StartConnectTask(int startDelay)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {                
            if (_isConnecting) return; // we are already connecting
            _isConnecting = true;
        }

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(startDelay);
                try
                {
                    CreateNewProxy();
                    _proxy.Login(Environment.UserName);

                    Dictionary<string,string> toSend;
                    while(_offlineValues.Get(out toSend))
                    {
                        _proxy.Update(toSend);
                    }
                    _isConnecting = false;
                    _isReady = true;
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void OnChannelFault(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((ICommunicationObject)sender).Abort();
        // reconnect...
        StartConnectTask(5000);
    }

    void Update(Dictionary<string,string> values)
    {
        if(_isReady)
        {
            // put values into a thread safe queue, to be sent once we come back online
            _offlineValues.Add(values);
        }
        else
        {
            _proxy.Update(values);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be interested in reading up on "Durable Messaging"

Comment: why is your class ctor named differently then your class ? 
ServerConnection

Comment: was a typo, now fixed with correct constructor name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the code - general impressions:

Having Task.Run run a sync method is kinda awkward - and not generally considered good use of Tasks.

It looks like you have the ability to lose work. For example, how do you deal with data you haven't sent yet - because of a connection issue or anything else. I think there are a couple of open edge cases. It doesn't look like you can call Update from multiple threads, for example - without losing something. What happens if you've got _offlineValues and you're shutting down?

I don't know what a TreadSafeStack is. That just sample-ish? You thinking ConcurrentQueue maybe?

The relationship between the actors seems awkward. Generally, I'd think you'd have a processor that does the communication separated from a work-queueing method that just submits work to the processor. The processor would detect the state of the proxy and reconnect it as needed.

The enqueueing of work can easily be made thread-safe. You probably don't want to wait on the service while enqueueing. Better to separate the long-running send from the quick-running submit.

I've got a similar thing - it's just the shell - I stripped out all the noise that makes my thing different than your thing - but maybe you can get what I'm talking about from it (my Enqueue would be analogous to your Update).

```
class Sender
{
  /// <summary>Synchronization primitive</summary>
  private static object sync = new object( );

  /// <summary>Processor wait this long before checking for work (if not nudged)</summary>
  private const int waitTimeOutMilliseconds = 5000;

  /// <summary>What the processor waits on to hear that there are things to do</summary>
  private ManualResetEvent nudge = new ManualResetEvent( false );

  /// <summary>The processor sets this when it's been signaled to stop and message processing is complete</summary>
  private ManualResetEvent done = new ManualResetEvent( false );

  /// <summary>A flag that will be set when the host wants to terminate the message queue processor</summary>
  private bool shutDown = true;

  /// <summary>A queue of messages that need to be sent</summary>
  private Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>( );


  /// <summary>Puts a message in the queue</summary>
  public void Enqueue( string message )
  {
    lock ( sync )
    {
      if ( shutDown ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "Shutting down - not accepting messages" );
      queue.Enqueue( message );
      nudge.Set( );
    }
  }

  /// <summary>Shuts down without waiting</summary>
  public void Stop( )
  {
    lock ( sync )
    {
      shutDown = true;
      nudge.Set( );
    }
  }

  /// <summary>Starts queue processing</summary>
  public void Start( )
  {
    if ( WaitForShutdown( 5000 ) )
    {
      lock ( sync )
      {
        shutDown = false;
        done.Reset( );
        nudge.Reset( );
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( Processor );
      }
    }
    else
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException( "Couldn't start - that's bad!" );
    }
  }

  /// <summary>Stops accepting messages on the queue, triggers shutdown and waits for the worker thread to complete.</summary>
  /// <param name="millisecondsToWait"></param>
  /// <returns>True if the thread stops in the time specified, false otherwise</returns>
  private bool WaitForShutdown( int millisecondsToWait )
  {
    Stop( );
    lock ( sync )
    {
      if ( shutDown ) return true;
    }
    return done.WaitOne( millisecondsToWait );
  }


  /// <summary>Worker thread method that writes the message</summary>
  private void Processor( object state )
  {

    var processList = new List<string>( );  //--> work we'll take out of the queue
    var cancel = false;  //--> a local representation of shutdown, we'll obtain while under a lock

    while ( true )
    {
      nudge.WaitOne( waitTimeOutMilliseconds );

      lock ( sync )
      {
        cancel = shutDown;
        while ( queue.Any( ) )
        {
          processList.Add( queue.Dequeue( ) );
        }
        nudge.Reset( );
      }

      foreach ( var message in processList )
      {
        try
        {
          // send to service...
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
          // reconnect or do whatever is appropriate to handle issues...
        }
        if ( cancel ) break;
      }

      processList.Clear( );

      if ( cancel )
      {
        done.Set( );
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens to all the messages if the process that `ClientProxyWrapper` is running in unexpectedly terminates?

You have no durability for your messages and thus can't guarantee that they will be delivered.  It would be better if you made use of a queuing system like MSMQ to store the messages and then process them from there.

A message queue can be transnational and the chance of loosing messages will be reduced.